# Ошибка "Could not open settings remapped class cache" при запуске Gradle на Андроид

Tags: gradle

Скачал Gradle и установил. Порадовался Welcom-у. Но при сборке или попытке что-то сделать - выходит ошибка:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Could not open settings remapped class cache for 8yjoihunpp0jrbx6dplfqlxe5 (/data/data/com.android.java/.gradle/caches/5.2/scripts-remapped/settings_6izy2gpmtky2pckv2cd4p82op/8yjoihunpp0jrbx6dplfqlxe5/settingseadbf4c451bc4876d277fc099d472843).
>
> Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/data/data/com.android.java/gradle0/app_HOME/gradle-5.6/samples/settings.gradle' (/data/data/com.android.java/.gradle/caches/5.2/scripts/8yjoihunpp0jrbx6dplfqlxe5/settings/settingseadbf4c451bc4876d277fc099d472843). Failed to initialize settings generic class cache for settings file '/data/data/com.android.java/gradle0/app_HOME/gradle-5.6/samples/settings.gradle' (/data/data/com.android.java/.gradle/caches/5.2/scripts/8yjoihunpp0jrbx6dplfqlxe5/settings/settingseadbf4c451bc4876d277fc099d472843)
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

воспроизводилась с jdk 13 версии, переставил jdk 11 и проблема ушла
https://github.com/pavjacko/renative/issues/323#issuecomment-545008100

Comment: @Coder Это вариант решения проблемы который может кому-то пригодиться. Хотя-бы до тех пор, пока грэдл не предложит какого-то реалистического решения либо пофиксит нормально. Ну или какую-то хоть мало-мальски понятную инструкцию  создаст как с этим бороться.

Comment: @V.March Согласен, спасибо.